# Shuffling through text onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I only recently picked up JavaScript and was wondering how to go about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
}
</script>
<p id='txt'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='CHANGE TEXT'/>
```

Above is a sample of the code I'm using. What I want is to be able to change the second text to a third, and a fourth, and so on; like cycling through the text values onclick, so it would display other text like:

*Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.*
*Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.*

I'm not sure if that's possible with the code I'm using, but I've been scouring the internet for a solution and I'm not really sure what I should search for.

Comment: where are the "second text" and "third"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but the following will toggle texts on button switch.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTextNum=0;
var texts = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4'];
function changeText(){
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = texts[currentTextNum];
currentTextNum++;
if (currentTextNum>texts.length) currentTextNum=0;
}
</script>
<p id='txt'>Text1</p>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='CHANGE TEXT'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to hold the strings:

```
var stringsArr = [ "first string...", "2nd string..", "3rd...", "4th..."];
```

Then, create a counter and increment it with each click;

```
var counter = 0;
function changeText(){
   counter++;
   document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = stringsArr[counter%(stringsArr.length-1)];
}
```